# INNER JOIN with another table gives one field twice?

Tags: php, mysql

I am very new to MySQL (sql in general) and I am trying to work something  out.
I have 2 tables, the first table contains a list of 'clients', the second table a list of 'users'. In the first table there are columns that contain the userID number of the 'contract manager' and the 'business development'. The ID is just a number, that references the ID number in the 'users' table. The users table then stores the First name, last name, etc of the user in question.

I am trying to run a query that will return the first and last names of both the contract manager, and the business development manager, and then use them in PHP.

I have the following query;

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    clients
INNER JOIN
    tenantusers AS cm ON cm.tenusr_ID = clients.cli_ContractManager
INNER JOIN
    tenantusers AS bd ON bd.tenusr_ID = clients.cli_BusinessDevelopment
ORDER BY cli_Name;
```

Which in MySQL dashboard returns the correct results, however I can't use this in PHP because

```
$t = $row['tenusr_FirstName'] . " " . $row['tenusr_LastName'];
```

Returns the last result of the query, and not the previous. And truth told, I have no idea how to get them.  I've tried to use `db.tenusr_FirstName` and it throws errors.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
+--------+----------+------------------+---------------+----------------------+-------------------------+
: cli_ID : cli_Name : cli_AddressLine1 : cli_Town      : cli_ContractManager  : cli_BusinessDevelopment :
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
: 1      : ACME     : On a street      : Makeuptington : 1                    : 2                       :
+--------+----------+------------------+---------------+----------------------+-------------------------+

+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+
: tenusr_ID : tenusr_Username : tenusr_LastName : tenusr_Email :
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
: 1         : Sam             : Smithers        : make@it.com  :
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
: 2         : Tom             : Watson          : tom@fake.net :
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I've added the tables - top is the clients table, second the users.

Comment: Have you tried using LEFT JOIN instead?

Comment: You just need to specify the columns you need instead of using `*`. That way you can assign an alias. Then just use the alias you assigned in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have columns with the same name in PHP. You'll want to SELECT only the columns you need, and alias the name columns with `AS`

```
SELECT 
    cm.tenusr_Username AS contract_FirstName, 
    cm.tenusr_LastName AS contract_LastName, 
    bd.tenusr_Username AS business_FirstName, 
    bd.tenusr_LastName AS business_LastName 
    ....
```

You can then use

```
$t = $row['contract_FirstName'] . " " . $row['contract_LastName'];
```

Comment: I've added my table layout, I think I confused matters.

Comment: I'll tweak the answer with the correct column names, but other than that, this should still work. If you're not getting the correct columns, you may need to use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` as Robert Lee suggested.

Comment: !! Excellent!! Thank you anyber.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is also right.  I left `clients.*` in which will select all rows from clients if you need them, but you should omit it if you don't need that.

```
SELECT 
    clients.*,  cm.FirstName as CMFirstName, cm.LastName as CMLastName, bd.FirstName as BDFirstName, bd.LastName as BDLastName
FROM
    clients
INNER JOIN
    tenantusers AS cm ON cm.tenusr_ID = clients.cli_ContractManager
INNER JOIN
    tenantusers AS bd ON bd.tenusr_ID = clients.cli_BusinessDevelopment
ORDER BY cli_Name;
```

In PHP

```
$bd = $row['BDFirstName'] . " " . $row['BDLastName']; 
$cm = $row['CMFirstName'] . " " . $row['CMLastName'];
```

If not all users will have a contract manager and business development person you should change your `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN` so it will include clients without one or the other or without both.